# Can I distribute a .app binary to devices registered in the provisioning profile?

Tags: ios

I have built my binary using a valid provisioning profile on my development machine. Can I then send the .app file to someone who's phone is registered in provisioning profile even if they do not have the development certificates on their machine? Can they just load it through iTunes?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using Testflightapp for distributing your ad-hoc builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you need to build an ad-hoc distribution.

this is a good link on how to do that.

http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

you can also distribute the ad hoc build over the internet like so.

http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution

Comment: Thank you, so then the only way to get a non adhoc build onto a device is syncing it with the computer that built the binary?

Comment: The over the internet article method seems convoluted & overkill. From what I understand if you build an ad-hoc distribution testers can then just drag the IPA file into iTunes.

Comment: No, you can sync it with any computer.  We use over the air and people love it. But it's up to you.

Comment: Okay. Can you load an ad hoc using any computer or just over the air format does that?

Comment: Both adhoc and over the are will enable any iPad listed in the distribution profile to be able to load the app. Either from a PC/Mac or over the air.